# Google maps: can you embed more data in the polyline than lat/lon?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I know you can get the Lat/Lon back from a polyline through the click event.

However, all my data is keyed by TIME, not Lat/Lon.  There's likely too much data to go through to search for a particular lat/lon, too.

Can I add any information to the Polyline so that it gives me back some key (ideally time) that I can then search through and find the rest of my data?

All my research says no, without pulling all the data out and re-keying it, or simply brute-force searching my db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're in a javascript environment... GPolyline and other overlays are javascript objects. It is entirely correct and possible to add your own properties to these overlays when you add them.

So you can do:

```
myPolyline = new GPolyline(latlngs);
myPolyline.myspecialtimevalue = sometimevalue;
map.addOverlay(myPolyline);
```

In the click event that you register you can then happily examine .myspecialtimevalue on the clicked polyline.

Duncan.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  Any idea if the latlon object passed back in the click event is the same object that I pass in?  That way I can set 'myspecialtimevalue' per vertex?

Comment: The API documentation is here:  http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GPolygon it does say that a Glatlng is passed.. so I assume its the clicked vertex.. You could of course put your "myspecialtimevalue" on each of the vertexes before passing the array of Glatlngs to the GPolygon constructor.. Good luck!